# How do you pass exception arguments to python unittest mock side effect?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, boto

How do you pass exceptions that require arguments as mock side_effects?

I'm trying to test for assertRaises of boto.exception.EC2ResponsError, but get a "TypeError: **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)" in _mock_call.

```
@mock_ec2
@patch.object(Ec2Region, 'connect')
def test_ec2_get_raises(self, mock_connect):
    conn = boto.connect_ec2()
    mock_connect.return_value = conn
    reservation = conn.run_instances('ami-1234abcd')
    instance = reservation.instances[0]
    Ec2Instance.objects.create(region=self.region, account=self.account,
                               instance_id=instance.id)
    mock_connect.side_effect = boto.exception.EC2ResponseError
    self.assertRaises(
        boto.exception.EC2ResponseError,
        Ec2Instance.ec2_get, self.account, self.region)
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_ec2_get_raises (session_ec2.tests.test_instance.Ec2InstanceTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bschott/.virtualenvs/session-ec2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/moto/core/models.py", line 70, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bschott/.virtualenvs/session-ec2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/bschott/Source/session-ec2/session_ec2/tests/test_instance.py", line 84, in test_ec2_get_raises
    Ec2Instance.ec2_get, self.account, self.region)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 475, in assertRaises
    callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bschott/Source/session-ec2/session_ec2/models/instance.py", line 110, in ec2_get
    connection = region.connect(account)
  File "/Users/bschott/.virtualenvs/session-ec2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 955, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bschott/.virtualenvs/session-ec2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1010, in _mock_call
    raise effect
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: You may find your answer in the sources (https://code.google.com/p/mock/source/browse/mock.py)

Answer (score 9):

As documented in [Calling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#calling) section you can use both instance or class in `side_effect` initialization. Moreover you can use a callable that raise your desired exception.

When class is used to define `side_effect` and the desired exception has not the trivial empty constructor you will get an exception like the one you had because `mock` framework doesn't know how to build that exception.

In your case you can use something like

```
mock_connect.side_effect = boto.exception.EC2ResponseError(400, "My reason", "my body")
```