# assign mock side_effect to a boto exception and assert calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a class that uses boto to download a file from s3, the method uses the **S3Connection** class to initiliase a connection and later on uses the **get_key** method to get the 'file'.
Here is the code block

```
import sys

from boto.exception import S3ResponseError, S3DataError
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s3conn = S3Connection(
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                host=HOST,
                is_secure=True
        )
        self.bucket = self.s3conn.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    def get_file(self, key):
        try:
            return self.bucket.get_key(key)
        except (S3ResponseError, S3DataError):
            sys.exit(3)
```

I want to mock out the get_bucket method and give it a side_effect of **S3ResponseError**, so that I can alo mock out the **sys.exit** method and assert it was called.

Here is how I am doing it.

```
import unittest
import mock
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError, S3DataError
from mymodule import MyClass

class TestS3(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.key = 'sample/bubket/key.txt'
        self.myclass = MyClass()

    def test_my_method(self):
        exit_method = (
            'mymodule.'
            'sys.'
            'exit'
        )
        s3_get_bucket = (
            'mymodule.'
            'S3Connection.'
            'get_bucket'
        )


        with mock.patch(s3_get_bucket) as mocked_bucket, \
            mock.patch(exit_method) as mocked_exit:
                mocked_bucket.side_effect = S3ResponseError
                self.myclass.get_file(self.key)
                mocked_exit.assert_called_once_with(3)
```

However, the assertion is failing, any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is that `MyClass.get_file()` doesn't call `get_bucket()`. That's why you're not seeing the call to `sys.exit()`. Either mock `get_key()` or call `get_bucket()`.

Comment: I got the test to pass by importing `from boto.s3.connection import Bucket  # noqa`, in the my_module file, and patching it. 
This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677100/how-do-you-pass-exception-arguments-to-python-unittest-mock-side-effect) also helped me. I assigned the mock side_effect as `mocked_bucket.side_effect = S3ResponseError(
                403, "Forbidden.", "The Credentials are wrong."
            )
`
What I am not sure is if importing a class (**Bucket**) that is not being used directly, to make patching easier, is good practice ?

Comment: Doesn't sound like good practice to me, @GideonMaina. Try moving the same import to the test instead of `my_module`. It's still weird, but I'm more tolerant of weirdness in my tests. However, you might want to think about what you're trying to mock in the first place. When I tried to run your sample code, it was trying to connect to AWS. Think about where [your seams are](http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/Seams-Mocks-and-Functions.aspx), and consider mocking all of that out.

Comment: Yes I will refactor and update the test after testing, +1 for the link.